# Where to ask CS algorithm questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a particular algorithm question that I am struggling to find optimal solution.

I have a solution that isn't optimal and I want suggestions on a better solution.
I also can't determine runtime complexity of my non-optimal solution, and want guidance on that.

Is stackoverflow.com the site for this type of question? If not, where? softwareengineering.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @jhpratt there is a  BIG disclaimer missing from your comment.... A)codereview has VERY strict on topic rules, so please check their help center/meta before just posting on there. B) the OP's solution has to be code, not an algo to go on codereview (it's unclear here if he just has the algo in pseudo code or actually implemented something, even if I do agree it's likely code)  C) afaik, codereview will not help him calculate the complexity